# как оптимизировать запрос чтобы два раза не обращаться к таблице order_split_mark_details

Tags: sql

```
if (select count(status)
    from order_split_mark_details os(nolock)
    where os.pcode=@vcode and status = 6276687) =
    (select count(status)
    from order_split_mark_details os(nolock)
    where os.pcode=@vcode)
    begin
        update o set status = 6276687
        from order_split_mark o(nolock)
        where o.vcode=@vcode
    end
```

Comment: IF ((select case when count(status) = sum(case when status = 6276687 then 1 else 0 END) then 1 else 0 END from order_split_mark_details os (nolock) where os.pcode=@vcode) = 1)
 Begin
  ...
 End

Comment: спасибо большое